# Which is the most efficient way to level up my TI5 compendium?

Tags: dota-2

I have bought my TI5 compendium, is there a way I can level up my compendium by playing games and still be able to reach 250+ levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the only way to level your compendium up is detailed in the compendium (Correct predictions, and various other things, see the compendium).

Apart from that, the only other (free) way to get compendium levels/points is to play games. There is a random drop chance (I've gotten 3 x 25 points in about 10 games).

Simply put: You are very unlikely to get to level 250 without spending money, unless you get all of your predictions right and playing a LOT of games.

Comment: That sounds a little not so encouraging. I was hoping that atleast the compendium points will be on sale like last year, but it is not so.

Comment: @Rai - Compendium points are on sale like last year. $9.99 for 2400 (24 lvls) points, $4.99 for 1100 points (11 lvls), and $2.49 for 500 points (5 lvls).

Comment: @ScottO I believe when he says "on sale" he means at a discount. That's how I interpreted it at least.

Comment: @ScottO I meant the 0.99$ compendium points which was on sale last year. And it also dropped a lot in game which made it real easy to level up compendium.